Roberta for sentence similarity
I have a pre trained roberta model. And have a dataset having two sentence pairs with a label that indicated whether the sentence pair is similar or not. I want to use that roberta model to do that.
I want to get sentence embeddings for both of sentences and use them to find the similarity using cosine similarity. Could you please tell me how to do that? or Any resources ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The concept of extracting embeddings and calculating the cosine similarity can be referred to as "Semantic Search". You can use the sentence-transformers library.
Following is a link to a quick way to use semantic search with Sentence-transformers.
https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/semantic-search/README.html
You can train the embeddings for your task using sentence-transformers or you can fine-tune the model for your task using the HuggingFace Trainer API.
Regards,

Thank you for the valuable comment, But the problem is my pre trained roberta model is for non-english language. Can I use roberta model in sentence transformer library
